# Navigation bar disappears

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

The navigation bar is fixed at the header and when the menu icon is clicked the entire container slides to right

This is my main page

[image: main page]

When the menu icon is clicked
[image: Home page when clicked on menu icon]

But when the page is scrolled down and clicked on menu icon, the header disappear

[image: Home page when clicked on menu icon when scrolled]

This is my css code

```
.content
{
    position:relative;

    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.header
{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  float: none !important;
clear: both !important;
  background-color:#19b8df;
  left:0;
  top:0;
 z-index: 999999;
}

.menu
{
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;

}
```

This is my html code

```
<div class="header">
        <div class="menu"><span><a href="#menu"><img src="images/menu.png" /></a></span>
        </div>

        <div class="searchicon"><a href="search.html"><img src="images/active-search.png" /></a>
        </div>

    </div>
```

My jquery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js"></script>
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('bav#menu').mmenu();

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created 2 links both have href attribute pointing to a location. In HTML if you click a link with a location, the particular location loads and your current link or page is lost.

Your header is in your current page and you are loading another page after clicking.

Comment: The other link is a search icon which loads a separate page.

Answer (score 0):

1. `<a href="#menu">`

Above line means you are linking to an element within same page with a name attribute value as "menu" example :

2. `<a href="search.html">`

Above line means you are linking to another page itself, hence you are getting blank page because you might not have a search.html page or using a blank search.html page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my question is not about getting a blank page. The search icon works great. My question was, the navigation bar in the header disappears when I scroll down and click the menu icon,else everything works fine.